# 2 Outer Joins from one table

Tags: mysql, join

I wanted to learn about web development so I made website with where users can vote on movies, and have issues with making a query for what I need. My tables are as follows:

```
--rtable--
+-----------+------------+------------+
| movieid   | rating     | userid     |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1         | 9          | 27         |
| 2         | 8          | 27         |
| 1         | 10         | 31         |
| 1         | 7          | 42         |
| 2         | 8          | 31         |
+-----------+------------+------------+
--mtable--
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| movieid   | moviename  | movielink  | director   |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Foo        | foo.com    | bob        |
| 2         | Bar        | bar.com    | steve      |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I wanted to make a query to for movie name, movie link, avg(rating), and the users rating (if exists), descending by avg(rating)

```
--desiredtable (if userid == 42)--
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| moviename |  movielink | avgrating  | yourrating |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| Foo       | foo.com    | 8.66       | 7          |
| Bar       | bar.com    | 8          | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I've managed to get moviename + movielink + avgrating working with OUTER LEFT JOIN but I'm scratching my head as to how to add yourrating. I've tried doubling up on OUTER JOIN and using sub-queries but can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I have so far that works

```
SELECT mtable.moviename, mtable.movielink, ROUND(AVG(rtable.rating), 2) AS avgrating, 
FROM mtable LEFT OUTER JOIN rtable ON rtable.movieid = mtable.movieid GROUP BY mtable.charid ORDER BY AVG(rtable.rating) DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the rtable twice on the mtable, once to get all ratings for the average, once to get the user's rating. You also need to supply the userid for which r2 is filtered within the on clause. That filter criterion in the on clause will apply to r2 only, not the entire dataset.

```
SELECT mtable.moviename, mtable.movielink, ROUND(AVG(r1.rating), 2) AS avgrating, max(r2.rating) as yourrating
FROM mtable m LEFT OUTER JOIN rtable r1 ON r1.movieid = m.movieid
LEFT JOIN rtable r2 on  r2.movieid=m.movieid and r2.userid=...
GROUP BY m.movieid, m.moviename, m.movielink
ORDER BY AVG(r1.rating) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped me out here.